# How to find Azure AKS Outgoing IP

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

If I create a cluster with an Ingress it creates a service with a public IP that I can target with my DNS for ingoing traffic.
However if I use that IP to whitelist for a DB connection etc it doesn't work.
How can I find the outgoing IP address for my whitelist?

Comment: Your question is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466101/how-to-get-hold-of-the-azure-kubernetes-cluster-outbound-ip-address/69473551#69473551

Comment: cool this worked, thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest create the Public IP (only the IP, not the LoadBalancer) upfront and then assign it to the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: YOUR_STATIC_IP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Note: Check also the SKU for the public IP, as the IP could change when you use the Basic SKU.

Comment: Yes, this is probably better approach next time. Thanks

Comment: Great. Could you please mark the answer as correct to help other users who maybe will have the same question ?

Comment: @philip-welz, this approach solves the problem of a definite egress public IP only if the AKS load balancer SKU is `Basic` and there is only one public `LoadBalancer` type Service on it. When multiple addresses are configured on the Azure Load Balancer, any of these public IP addresses are a candidate for outbound flows, and one is selected at random. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress#create-a-service-with-the-static-ip). **[contd]**

Comment: When you use a `Standard SKU` load balancer, by default the AKS cluster automatically creates a public IP in the AKS-managed infrastructure resource group and assigns it to the load balancer outbound pool. To use your own (static provisioned) public IP addresses for outbound traffic on an AKS cluster with `Standard SKU` load balancer, please follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#update-the-cluster-with-your-own-outbound-public-ip).